# Java Process return permission denied only sometime.

Tags: java, bash, process

I am running a shell script from Java. it work most of the time, but occasionally it raise exception "permission denied"

```
  PrintWriter writer = new PrintWriter(folder + cmdFile, "UTF-8");
    writer.println("#!/bin/bash");
    writer.println(commandLine.toString());
    writer.close();

    Process processUtil = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("/bin/chmod +x " + folder +  cmdFile );
    Process process = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(folder + "./" + cmdFile);
    try {
        int processResponseCode = processUtil.waitFor();

        processUtil = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("sleep 0.1s");
        processResponseCode = processUtil.waitFor();


        processResponseCode = process.waitFor();

        processUtil = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(" rm " + folder + cmdFile);
        processResponseCode = processUtil.waitFor();
```

The exception

```
 java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "/tmp/./cmd755784": error=13, Permission denied
```

any idea what could be causing this ?

Comment: does it have right permissions to run?

Comment: as you can see in the code, I add that permission

Comment: for me should be just chmod +x cmdFile folder

Comment: Is there a reason you're using shell commands embedded in java instead of using the built-in `File` object?

Answer (score 0):

Please check if there is any other process using or holding a handle of this directory/file that is being removed. User fuser command to check. Based on the output of fuser, the script should wait for some more time and set a timeout to handle other exception cases. This is out of purview of the question, but you need to improve your coding in the following:

1. Write a shell script which can arguments, in this case they are the folder path and file name
2. Invoke shell script by passing those args.
3. Process invocation should be asynchronous, meaning that the process should be invoked and waited upon in a loop or through a handle/signal to avoid indefinite waits.

PS: I would advice against using any scripting from Java unless there is no other way. Avoid it.

Answer (score 0):

Executing files from `/tmp` is sometimes an issue since `/tmp` is often mounted `noexec`.

Try running from a different directory.